# How to make a popup ride over a html page using chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Just like Pocket chrome app does it, where when you save a page, it shows a drag down/popup that shows that you've added the link to Pocket.

How is it possible to achieve something similar?

To give a visual example: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[Programmatic Injection](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi)** to inject and execute some JS code that modifies the web-pages DOM apropriately.

```
// In `background.js`:
...
var jsCode = [
    "var div = document.createElement('div');",
    "div.innerHTML = '...';",
    "div.style.position = 'fixed';",
    "div.style.zIndex = '9999';",
    "document.body.appendChild(div);"
].join("\n");
function injectPopover(tabId) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
        code: jsCode
    });
}
```

You will, also, need to set the necessary **[permissions](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions.html)** in your `menifest.json` depending on when/how you want your popover to be triggered (and on what web-pages).

If you are not familiar with the basic concepts of Chrome Extensions, the **[Getting-Started Guide](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html)** it the place to...start.

Comment: I am familiar with it, but I am just not sure how to inject an entire html page and not just html string. Maybe injecting an iframe would be the way to go?

Comment: Why inject an entire page ? If you want a popover, you just inject the JS that modifies the existing page's DOM to add (and then hide) the popover. If the code you want to inject is lengthy, you can inject a script instead, e.g.: `chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "relative/path/to/myscript.js"});

Comment: Because I was a bit confused about the security rules and whether it is a great idea to inject scripts in itself. Wont injecting an entire page give me a better control over the UI that I want to displayed?

Comment: Injecting a page doesn't make sense (maybe you have something else in mind). Either inject some JS (to manipulate the original DOM) or **open** a new page/**replace** the original (with what ever content you want it to have). But the second case is **not** a popover. The advantage of injecting JS into the orifinal page is that it is more clear for the user (you don't navigate away from the page) and you can clean-up on yourself (e.g. have a close button that removes your popover and leaves the original page intact, so the user can continue doing what (s)he was doing.

Comment: Ah. That's a great example. One final question: How does the document variable know which tab I'm talking about to do changes to the html? Shouldn't I pass some kind of tabId to make it work?

Comment: I figured it out myself. Though there is a tiny js bug in your code. I was following the examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script and it was giving me a CSP error.

Comment: If you found an error please let me know, so I can correct it for others. (I already corrected a couple of wrong quotes.)